# How to Detect Collisions with multiple Items in the Same Array VB?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, collision

I would like to have two items in the same array be able to collide with each other and the only possible way of achieving this that I could think of would be to create a for next loop inside of a for next loop. This is what I have got so far:

```
for i = 0 to arrEnemies.Length - 1
  for x = 0 to arrEnemies.length - 1
    if arrEnemies(i).bounds.intersectswith(arrEnemies(x)) then
      msgbox("hit")
    end if
  next
next
```

Although this doesn't work, I also tried creating a seperate array, although both ways that I have tried so far seem to detect collisons with itself, which isn't what I want.

Thanks in advance,
James

Comment: If you don't want it to detect itself as a collision, check that i <> x.  Without knowing more about the overall game framework, I can't make a suggestion although having loops inside of loops is something you want to avoid (it will work okay with small numbers of enemies but if that number gets big, watch out).

Comment: Please can you give a bit more information about your arrEnemies array, is it an array of pictureboxes?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not posting the array is of picture boxes that I want to test collision between